# Next JS 13 project does not deploy. Vercel returns prerender-error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

When I deploy the project, `vercel` returns me error. In localhost there is no problems.   I dont know what is my mistake. The error is that
[image]

The folder structure
[image]

And my detail page

```
import NewsDetailContainer from "@/containers/NewsDetailContainer";
import axios from "axios";

const DetailPage = async ({ params }) => {
  let newsDetail;
  const getNewsDetail = async (id) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api/v1/news/${id}`);
    return res.data;
  };

  newsDetail = await getNewsDetail(params.id);

  return <NewsDetailContainer newsInfo={newsDetail} />;
};

export default DetailPage;
```

Comment: Are you using the /app directory in next 13?

Comment: @Designly yes src/app/xeberler(or news)/[id] but into [id] (or DetailPage) ```NewsDetailContainer``` is out of app. But I tried everything into app folder and nothing happened

Comment: Two things I see right away: 1. Where are you getting the variable `id` from? Did you forget to deconstruct `params`? Also, your API endpoint is not a FQDN. Perhaps check the results your getting back from axios in the logs?

Comment: Also, you'd probably catch this error if you placed your axios request in a try, catch block.

Comment: I have cards and each card has id. When I click it, the route change for example ```<Link href={`/xeberler/${news[0]?.id}`} prefetch={false}>``` and my api is example. My real api is ```https://badminton.com/v1/```

Comment: @Designly I can not catch this error. Because in localhost everything works, but in deploy I have some errors

Comment: Ok, I see where you're pushing params.id to the component. You've declared the component in the same file.

Comment: @Designly I tried what you said. But vercel returned again same error. But I have solved this problem with installing new next app. And I copied src, next.module, and installing package json. And It deployed. I think it is not a true solution but I have no other choise

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I created new project and copied `src`, `next-modules` and `package-json`. New project worked